# Recaptcha Too long: Maximum of '50' characters

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, captcha, recaptcha

I'm using recaptcha in my website and suddenly it stoped working, when I click in the text field it gives a message:Too long: Maximum of '50' characters, I didn't find references of this error on google.

TypeError: recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_canary.js line 142: `a("recaptcha_response_field").setAttribute("placeholder",b))},_finish_widget:function(){var a=$.$,b=Z,c=b.theme;c in{blackglass:1,clean:1,custom:1,red:1,white:1}||(c="red");$.theme||($.theme=c);"custom"!=$.theme?$._init_builtin_theme():$._set_style("");c=document.createElement("span");c.id="recaptcha_challenge_field_holder";c.style.display="none";a("recaptcha_response_field").parentNode.insertBefore(c,a("recaptcha_response_field"));a("recaptcha_response_field").setAttribute("autocomplete","off");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We suddenly started receiving calls about this and located the problem with maxlength=50. In testing around 6:15 EST, the maxlength field was no longer included.

Google may have realized their error and pushed out a fix.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue if you are using jquery validator add a rule for the field recaptcha_challenge_field is a hidden value and recaptcha is now rendering it with a max-length=50 that's why the jquery validator throws the error.

Comment: This is happening for me even though I'm not using jquery validation.  I am using ASP.Net MVC validation, however.  It started happening yesterday.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with asp mvc but it could be related to the same thing, check how to set rules specific for the inputs